# CodenameOne - fixing Calendar get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) bigger value than expected

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat, dayofweek

I am creating a workaround to fix the SimpleDateFormat "clone" class of CN1 in my app.

I cannot use other classes from pure Java.

I used this instruction in my CN1 app

```
int dayNumber=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

for handling the u letter in the format string.

At the time of the creation of this post it's Wednesday
dayNumber happens to have value of 4.

So I replaced that instruction with

```
int dayNumber=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
```

because I found in Oracle documentation

```
Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)
```

I would like to know if it is correct
so that I have the 7 days of the week covered so it is just as

```
(1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)
```

and I can have the right u value for Java and Android compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is not yet part of CodeName One, and that therefore you cannot use it in your case. Apart from special situations like yours no one should use `Calendar` since it is poorly designed and long outdated. Everyone should use java.time.

To get (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday) from `Calendar` (the numbers that you would get by default from java.time):

```
    int dayNumber = (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7 + 1;
```

Seen under modulo 7 I am first adding 5, then 1, so 6 in total, which is the same as subtracting 1. I am using this trickery to make sure I get a number in the 1 through 7 interval (which we don’t always by simply subtracting 1 from the return value from `Calendar`).

I am demonstrating the edge cases and using java.time for it:

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.SEPTEMBER, 5);
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay);
    
    int dayNumber = (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7 + 1;
    
    System.out.format("%s: %s = %d%n", ld, ld.getDayOfWeek(), dayNumber);
    
    ld = ld.plusDays(1);
    startOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
    c = GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay);
    
    dayNumber = (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7 + 1;
    
    System.out.format("%s: %s = %d%n", ld, ld.getDayOfWeek(), dayNumber);
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2021-09-05: SUNDAY = 7
> 2021-09-06: MONDAY = 1
> ```

Disclaimer: I don’t know the CodeName One `Calendar` in particular. I strongly expect it to behave exactly the same as the original `java.util.Calendar`, and my answer is based on the assumption that it does.